# iOS - Nearby Places on Google Maps

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am working on a feature of my app that lets the user search for nearby pharmacies. I am trying to keep things simple and i would like to display the standard places icons and labels which are shown on google maps app. I searched extensively but i haven't found a way to do it. Is there a way to display all the pharmacies as standard ?

Currently i created a GMSMarker for every pharmacy found on a radius of 5km with custom icons and a custom label for the title. But i ran into issues when zooming out, the icons and titles  keep their size and overlap.

[image: This is how i would like to display all the places]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign **position** for the markers, so that it will be shown till there

`GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: The GMSMarker is not the problem. I would like to display the standard places icons and labels without using GMSMarker. In Google Maps if i tap on a red dot for pharmacy only then a GMSMarker appears. I would like to replicate that functionality.